# I keep getting wrong ID and number of threads with openmp

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "omp.h"

void main() {
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads;
    int ID = omp_get_thread_num;
    printf("%d %d \n",ID,numberOfThreads);
}
}
```

The answers I get are:

```
4196016 4196064 
4196016 4196064 
4196016 4196064 
4196016 4196064
```

I compile the program with the following command:

```
gcc -O3 -fopenmp -Wall test.c
```

I only get some warning messages:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:24: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer 
without a cast [enabled by default]
  int numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads;
                    ^
test.c:9:11: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer 
without a cast [enabled by default]
  int ID = omp_get_thread_num;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to print the addresses of those functions, you should be using a function pointer and the `%p` printf specifier.  If you want the values, you should probably *call* the functions: `omp_get_num_threads()` and `omp_get_thread_num()` - note the `()` to indicate function call.

Comment: thanks for response! I see the problem -_-
I used to program in Java and it gives error if we wrongly using the functions or variables, little spoiled!

Comment: Please do not put words like "(solved)" in the question title. The fact that you have marked an answer as solution already indicates that the problem has been solved.

Comment: understood &  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are functions, so

```
int numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads;
```

must be

```
int numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
```

And

```
int ID = omp_get_thread_num;
```

must be

```
int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
```